# In laravel http:// or https:// not showing when I check viewsource of page

Tags: laravel, https

APP_URL: https://youdomain.com

I write assets URL like `{{asset('assets/front/css/plugin.css')}}` in laravel blade file.

But when I check page view source then show only

```
href="//yourdomain.com/assets/front/css/plugin.css"
```

Why not showing `https://` in viewsource in laravel

Comment: Do you know what `//yourdomain.com` actually means? You don't need to add the protocol, `//` here means use the protocol used from the server (in your case, `https`)

Comment: I know but my problem is why not showing full protocol name when I check viewsource

Comment: Because using `//yourdomain.com` takes the protocol from the actual domain. No need to specify it. Why do you want/need to see the protocol in the source?

Answer (score 1):

You dont Need //
just your endpoint
what is yourdomain here?